# Can we use Atiyah-Macdonald Proposition 1.11(ii) to prove the Lagrange interpolation theorem?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Two Theorems:

**Theorem 1** (Atiyah-Macdonald, Proposition 1.11(ii)): Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and let $\mathfrak p_1,\dots,\mathfrak p_n$ be prime ideals in $A$, and let $\mathfrak a$ be an ideal of $A$ such that $\mathfrak a\subset\mathfrak p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_n$.  Then $\mathfrak a\subset\mathfrak p_i$ for some $i$.

*Proof.* Induction on $n$.  The case $n=1$ is clear.  Suppose $n>1$ and suppose that $\mathfrak a\not\subset\mathfrak p_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.  By the inductive hypothesis, for each $j=1,\dots,n$ we have $\mathfrak a\not\subset \bigcup_{j\ne i}\mathfrak p_j$, so there is some $x_j\in\mathfrak a\setminus \bigcup_{j\ne i}\mathfrak p_j$ for each $j$.  Now let

$$
y=\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i} x_j
$$

Certainly $y\in\mathfrak a$.  We claim that $y\not\in\mathfrak p_k$ for each $k$.  Indeed, suppose $y\in\mathfrak p_k$ for some $k$.  Then every term of the sum except the $i=k$ term is a multiple of $x_k$, so is contained in $\mathfrak p_k$.  So, after subtracting these terms, we see that

$$
\prod_{j\ne k}x_j\in\mathfrak p_k
$$

Therefore, since $\mathfrak p_k$ is a prime ideal, we must have $x_j\in\mathfrak p_k$ for some $j\ne k$, contradicting the definition of $x_j$.

Therefore, $y\in\mathfrak a\setminus\mathfrak p_1\cup\cdots\cup\mathfrak p_n$.  $\Box$

**Theorem 2** (Lagrange Interpolation): Let $k$ be a field and let $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n\in k$.  Then there exists a polynomial $f\in k[x]$ of degree at most $n-1$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$ for each $i$.

*Proof.*  The polynomial

$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^jy_j\prod_{j\ne i}\frac{(x-x_j)}{(x_i-x_j)}
$$
will do. $\Box$

There's a striking similarity between these proofs - they both employ the same sum-product trick to get to their result.  I therefore thought it would be easy to come up with a proof of Theorem 2 from Theorem 1, but I didn't manage to get there.  Am I missing something obvious?

**Note:** I am aware that the Lagrange interpolation theorem can be proved using the Chinese remainder theorem - and indeed there are similar similarities between the proofs of those two theorems.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 1 is false. You better take $x_i\in \mathfrak a$ such that $x_i\notin \mathfrak p_j$ whenever $j\neq i$ (this forces $x_i\in \mathfrak p_i$).

Comment: @user218931 No, my proof is right.  And I'm don't see how you're so sure that such an $x_i$ exists.

Comment: @user218931 I'll add some more details to the proof so you can see how it works.

Comment: You can assume that $\mathfrak a\not\subseteq \cup_{j\neq i}\mathfrak p_j$ for all $i$ by using an inductive argument on the number of primes. How do you see in your proof that $y\notin \mathfrak p_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: @user218931 Ah yes, you're right.  Let me rewrite the proof.

Comment: @Donkey_2009, did you check your proof? Can you explain your idea?